# How do i wait for 2 dateChange events and execute a function

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have 2 MatDatepickers for start and end dates and i'm firing a searchFilter function on dateChange like so:

```
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Start date" 
(dateChange)="searchFilter($event.value)">

<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker2" placeholder="End date" 
(dateChange)="searchFilter($event.value)">
```

I need to apply my searchFilter with the event data if both of these are fired. I'm new to Observables. I'm aware of the zip method that i can use to wait for 2 observables, but how can i specifically zip these and these events only? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "how can i specifically zip these and these events only"?

Comment: You can create two-way binding and check if there is value on end date and vice versa to trigger function call.

Comment: @Vinko Yeah simply using local references or ngmodel does the job. I was just overthinking it. Thanks. You can post it as an answer if you wish to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create template-driven forms by using NgModel directive.

```
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Start date"[(ngModel)]="this.startDate"(dateChange)="searchFilter()">
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker2" placeholder="End date" [(ngModel)]="this.endDate" (dateChange)="searchFilter()">
```

and in component.ts declare variables and initialize it, and create function

```
startDate: any = '';
endDate: any = '';
searchFilter(): any {
 if(this.startDate != '' && this.endDate != '') do something
}
```